# filtering values from a dictionary based on keys and values from other dictionaries

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, filter, merge

I have 4 dictionaries and I am trying to modify the values of a dictionary based on keys and values from other dictionaries as follows:

```
dict1 = {'Name_1': u'KEVIN', 'Name_0': u'ANDREW','Name_2': u'LUCA'}
dict2 = Counter({'Fin': 300, 'CD': 223, 'Ind':155, 'Tec': 154, 'HC': 100, 'CS': 95, 'Mat': 88, 'Com': 68, 'Unc': 61, 'Ene': 43, 'Uti': 18})
dict3 = Counter({'Name Missing': 762, 'ANDREW': 300, 'LUCA': 155, 'KEVIN': 88})
dict4 = {'Ind': 'LUCA', 'Mat': 'KEVIN', 'Fin': 'ANDREW'}
```

Expected number of hobbies per name 435
I am looking for a way in which the count from 2dict replaces the value count with a name so that every name gets more or less 435. I don't think I need all of the dictionaries but I don't really know how to combine them to achieve this. 
Expected result:

```
dict2 = Counter({'Fin':'ANDREW', 'CD':'LUCA', 'Ind':'LUCA', 'Tec':'KEVIN', 'HC':'KEVIN', 'CS':'ANDREW', 'Mat':'KEVIN', 'Com':'KEVIN', 'Unc':'LUCA', 'Ene':'ANDREW', 'Uti':'KEVIN'})
```

this calculation was made manually I am afraid :(

Comment: don't use words starting with digits as variable names: it's illegal.

Comment: Updated Francois. Merci pour le conseil